# Changing The Android APK Package Name From Script In Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am wondering how to change the package name of the final apk from the code. I am writing an editor plugin script. this script should be able to  change the final apk's package name.
here is the code:

```
PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier = "com.myco.myapp";
```

but it doesn't work.
any one...
**UPDATE:**
Code above works correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you see the changes in the Editor? Where are you calling this from?

Comment: oh, your are right, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I had the same problem in Unity 2019.1.10f1 for an Editor script I made to build Android applications. The line of code you shown didn't changed the package name of my application.

This line of code worked for me :

```
PlayerSettings.SetApplicationIdentifier(BuildTargetGroup.Android,"com.yourCompany.yourAppName");
```